# JIRA - Select issues where no subtask is assigned to the current user

Tags: filter, jira, jql

I would like to select all tasks assigned to the current user, where no subtasks are assigned to the current user.  This will let me make a report that warns a developer if they are currently accountable for a functional user story, but not working on any technical subtasks related to it.

I thought it would be this (using the [Scripted JQL functions](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions)):

```
assignee = currentUser()
and (issueFunction in parentsOf("assignee != currentUser()"))
```

Unfortunately this subquery does not include unassigned subtasks, despite the assignee presumably being `null` in this case.  I tried experimenting with multiple `issueFunction` clauses, but that seemed like a bit of a rabbit-hole when what I want is not that complicated.

An example of what I want in SQL would look something like this:

```
select distinct
    t.* from Task t
join
    Subtask st using (t.Id = st.TaskId)
where
    t.AssigneeId = CurrentUserId
    and st.AssigneeId != CurrentUserId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does what is needed. It excludes the sub-tasks that has assignee set to current user and then gets all the 
other parent tasks.

```
issuefunction in parentsOf("assignee != currentUser() or assignee is empty") 
AND assignee = currentUser() 
AND not (issuefunction in parentsof ("assignee = currentUser()"))
```